# Custom aws wrapper jar for only S3

Tags: java, rest, aws-sdk

I am working on amazon S3 file upload operation in java. Amazon provides aws java sdk for this purpose but the thing is the sdk is of 20 mb including its dependencies. What I want is, a library which have only functionality of S3 related operation.

P.S. I read that amazon provides REST API also. So, did anyone tried that api in java. If yes, please help me by sharing the code snippet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

aws now provides separate libraries too. If you are using maven then you can include just the s3 library. 
Below is the link for the same. 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.9.33

Comment: Thanks for the answer, found the solution. I added three libraries - aws-java-sdk-s3, aws-java-sdk-kms and aws-java-sdk-core